# Python. Compare list of words to list of letters

Tags: python

I have a list

```
stimuli_words = ["red","bird","ocean"]
```

and another list

```
stimuli_letters = ['b','i','r','d','r','e','d','o','c','e','a','n']
```

Is there a way to compare the second list to the first and return matched words? Order of words doesn't matter, but within-word letters should be in the right order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
stimuli_words = ["red","bird","ocean"]
stimuli_letters = ['b','i','r','d','r','e','d','o','c','e','a','n']
stimuli_string = ''.join(stimuli_letters)  # This becomes 'birdredocean'

for word in stimuli_words:
    if word in stimuli_string:
        print(word)
        # Do something else
```

Where basically first you create a string from the chars in `stimuli_letters` and then you search for each **word** in `stimuli_words` inside the string.

Of course this only works if the chars are in order in the second list. Otherwise it becomes exponentially complex.